# powershell:how to catch the error cause by invoke-sqlcmd?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I want to catch the invoke-sql if there is anything wrong. But when I run the following command, and if the $sql is invalid, it can't be caught. How to catch this exception?

```
 try {
     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sql -ServerInstance t1 -database db -QueryTimeout 65535 -ErrorAction 'Stop'
   } catch{
      "error when running sql $sql"
   }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have no issue, using a script called test.ps1

```
add-pssnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
get-host
$sql = "selects * from syscomments"
$server = ""
$database = ""
$username = ""
$password = ""
try {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sql -ServerInstance $server -database $database -QueryTimeout 65535 -ErrorAction 'Stop' -username $username -password $password
} catch {
  "error when running sql $sql"
  Write-Host($error)
}
```

And the output

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : 9ac019da-97bd-45d1-bfa5-65fb4d376dc6
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-AU
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

error when running sql selects * from syscomments

Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

what input parameters are you using, are you using powershell 1 or 2?

Comment: `$error` is a list of all errors in the current runspace.  Within the catch block you want to use `$_` to see the current error.

Comment: sorry, I checked my code again, it works, I must make some mistake during the test.

Comment: I need to add if you do not use -ErrorAction stop but use Continue or SilentlyContinue, then the exception will not be caught. My test is PS V5.1 and SQL Server 2016