# Powershell: error report while Import CSV file to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, csv, error-handling

How can I skip or say "error" on SQL server when the data does not match with data type?
such as ID has `nchar(2)` on SQL server and I have csv file that one of data is '1234' for ID.
How can I have error sign or error report for that data in SQL server.
It is ok that I can have separate excel file about all the errors.
I just want to know which data got error.

And make the script without stopping even there is an error.

Here is my script

```
$today = (get-date).Date
$DataImport = Import-Csv -Path (Get-ChildItem filename | where { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today } )    
$DataTable = Out-DataTable -InputObject $DataImport
write-DataTable -serverInstance servername -Database DBname -TableName Table name -Data $DataTable
```

Functions `Out-DataTable` and `Write-DataTable` have been defined.

Comment: Did your see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766250/powershellhow-to-catch-the-error-cause-by-invoke-sqlcmd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TRY and CATCH.

```
$today = (get-date).Date
TRY
{
$DataImport = Import-Csv -Path (Get-ChildItem filename | where { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today } )    
$DataTable = Out-DataTable -InputObject $DataImport
write-DataTable -serverInstance servername -Database DBname -TableName Table name    -Data $DataTable
}
CATCH 
{     
$_.Exception.Message
"PS code here that writes error to txt or to excel."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write-DataTable function is using the the .NET SqlBulkCopy class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx, unlike the T-SQL BULK INSERT command or some data loading utilities like SSIS, there's isn't an option to commit some rows and log error rows. You could play with changing the -BatchSize parameter to 1 instead of 50,000, this way it will commit each row and instead of rolling back entire batch and you can catch the exception. Note: This will be slower for large datasets.

Another solution is to use the T-SQL BULK INSERT command specifying an error file:

```
$query = "BULK INSERT dbname..table FROM 'C:\temp\test.csv' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', ERRORFILE = 'C:\temp\test.err')"
```

Then call the query using invoke-sqlcmd or sqlcmd.exe.