# Catch exception raised by invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: powershell

I want to catch the invoke-sqlcmd if there is anything wrong. But when I run the following command, and if the invoke-sqlcmd is invalid, it can't be caught. How to catch this exception?

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile "D:\Tables\Script_CreateTable.tab"
}

Catch{
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
$Time=Get-Date
"This script failed at $Time and error message was $ErrorMessage" | out-file D:\Log\CreateTable.log -append
}

Finally{

$Time=Get-Date
"This script made a read attempt at $Time" | out-file D:\Log   \CreateTable.log -append
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell:how to catch the error cause by invoke-sqlcmd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766250/powershellhow-to-catch-the-error-cause-by-invoke-sqlcmd)

Comment: His case was used -Query while my case was -InputFile

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this, but I'm guessing the error isn't a terminal exception. The solution to this is to add `-ErrorAction Stop` at the end of the command. Try:

```
try {
    Invoke-SqlCmd -InputFile "D:\Tables\Script_CreateTable.tab" -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $Time=Get-Date
    "This script failed at $Time and error message was $ErrorMessage" | out-file D:\Log\CreateTable.log -append
}
```

Or `-AbortOnError` which seems to be a cmdlet-specific parameter for `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.